# Adding fuzziness conditionally in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have ten or so fields in all my documents: One in particular is `product_code` which is unique per document and of type string.

I have a match query on `_all` that works well, but I would like to perform a "fuzzy match" while preserving the ability to search for exact `product_code`

Here's what I've attempted:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "match": {
                    "product_code": {
                        "query": searchString,
                        "operator": "AND"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "_all": {
                        "query": searchString,
                        "operator": "AND"
                        "fuzziness": 2,
                        "prefix_length": 2
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the fuzziness is being applied to searches for `product_code` as well because it's included in `_all`.

Is there a way to either perform the search on `product_code` first and if no results are found, perform the search on `_all`, or exclude `product_code` from the `_all` query?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can exlude `product_code` from _all using the following mappings.

```
PUT index_name
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {},
            "filter": {}
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "type_name": {
            "properties": {
                "product_code": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "include_in_all": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) search which also offer fuzziness.

Use the following query which use query string with AND operator and fuzziness settings

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "query_string": {
                    "fields": ["product_code", "other_field"],
                    "query": "this is my string",
                    "default_operator": "AND",
                    "fuzziness": 2,
                    "fuzzy_prefix_length": 2
                }
            }, {
                "match": {
                    "product_code": {
                        "query": "this is my string",
                        "operator": "AND"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there way to accomplish this in the query itself as opposed to changing the mapping?

Comment: which version of elasticsearch you are using?

Comment: then you alternatively use query_string, i have edited my answer for query string query with fuzziness

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. The query is returning all results. I'll bite the bullet and change the mapping to not include the product_code in _all. Thanks.